# ES6 modules export and import

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-modules

**foo.js**

```
const a = 1
const b = 2
const c = 3
let d = 4

export default { a, b }
export { c }
export d
```

What's the difference between exported `a, b, c, d`？

And how to `import` them correctly?

Does the `Babel` compilation will effect it?

Comment: `export d` doesn't seem to be valid syntax

Comment: The `a` and `b` variables are not exported. You are creating an object and export it under the `default` identifier. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can only `export` declarations (except for the default export) that means that:

```
 export d;
```

is invalid, it has to be:

```
 export const d = 1;
```

> And how to import them correctly?

```
 import main, { c, d } from "sth";
 const {a, b} = main;
```

You can import `c` and `d` in the same way, only the object properties `a` and `b` can't be accesed directly as you can't destructure objects inside the import statement, therefore you have to destructure them in a new line which is just ugly. To quote Bergi: "Don't do that", instead go with `c` or `d`.